# missing prefabs in project hierarchy

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I had a project in a computer A, everything was working just fine.

I cloned the same project to a computer B, everything running fine. I did some work on it, changing the scene, prefabs and other stuff, did some commits.

Lastly, I pull the project's new commits in computer A, but when I opened the project, the hierarchy shows that I have missing prefabs.

Any ideas of what I did wrong or how to fix it? Before the last commit in computer B, I saved the scene (of the missing prefabs) and the project as well. I still didn't delete and reinstall the project in A.

Comment: Do a `git status` on both machines and make sure they are up to date

Comment: Did you install any updates for unity in the meantime?

Comment: yes, they are in the same branch and commit, but the unity versions are different, A is 2018.1 and B is 2018.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are in the same branch and commit, but the unity versions are different, A is 2018.1 and B is 2018.2.6. – Daniel 31 mins ago

Happened to me for the same reason too. I reinitialized the prefabs again (disaster).
Try to pull the older commit and then paste the new one over it. You might still have some missing prefabs but significantly less. If that doesn't work just paste the .meta files.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "pull the older commit and then paste the new one over it"?

Comment: Pull an old commit (one that didn't have this issue)  and duplicate it. After that, pull the newest commit, copy and paste it in the old commit's folder.